# PHP cron job every 10 minutes to log out user on browser close

Tags: ajax

I read a lot but cannot find something that works.

I have a php query that sets the user status to 1 when logged in, and 0 when logged out.
At the moment, I have a timer for inactivity but this will not work if the user closes the browser.

I know the solution is somehow to use javascript to periodically call the server using ajax. But I am not sure how to do that

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

On page:

```
if ($_SESSION['last_action'] + (10*60) < time()) // Check if last action time wasn't less than 10 minutes ago.
{
    // Log user out.
}
else {
    $_SESSION['last_action'] = time();
}
```

Comment: this will not work on browser close as I mentioned above. I have that already

Comment: anyone can help out with this?